# python button command executing before click

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing code to pass two variables to a function on the click of a button. The issue is that it is doing so before the button is pressed. What am I doing wrong?

```
calcButton = Button(window, text="Calculate Weight",
                            command=window.calc(5,10))
        calcButton.place(x=225, y=85)
        answertextLabel = Label(window, text="Answer:")
        answertextLabel.place(x=225, y=65)
        answerLabel = Label(window, text=answervar)
        answerLabel.place(x=275, y=65)

    def calc(window, diameter, density):
        math = diameter + density
        print (math)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `window.calc(5,10)` the function gets executed.

You need to wrap it in another function:

```
command=lambda: window.calc(5,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the function as an argument to the `Button` constructor; you are passing the return value of one particular call to that function. Wrap the call in a zero-argument function to defer the actual call until the button is clicked.

```
calcButton = Button(window,
                    text="Calculate Weight",
                    command=lambda : window.calc(5,10))
```

Comment: Thank you. This works and now I'm beginning to understand why. I'll accept the answer when I'm able to!